# CMake [build] stuck on one percentage throughout build yet still builds

Tags: c++, cmake

When building with `cmake` no longer getting increasing percentages, just stuck at `40%`. The build still works.

```
[build] [ 40%] ...
[build] [ 40%] ...
[build] [ 40%] ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a permissions issue. Solved by changing the `build/CMakeFiles/Progress` directory to have correct ownership, e.g. using `chown` or `chmod`.

Same issue spotted in 2006: https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2006-October/011544.html